# django access another model through foreign key

Tags: django, django-admin

Let's say I've got models:

```
Class Author(models.Model):
    id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    dob = models.DateField() 

Class Note(models.Model):
    note = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)

Class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    pubdate = models.DateField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
```

And in admin.py:

```
Class BookInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Book

Class NoteInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Note

Class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Author
    inlines = [BookInline, NoteInline]

Class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Book
```

Users need to enter data from the AuthorAdmin page, and have an inline for entering Book data.

Ideally I'd like the note textfield to be part of the Book model, but the majority of the time it's unlikely to be used.

So I thought for the sake of database efficiency, I'd move it into a separate table. In the absence of properly working nested inlines (I tried the existing packages and ran into known bugs), the setup above works (i.e. having Note attached to Author rather than Book).

However when I then use BookAdmin I can't see any notes (as it's a foreign key to Author, not Book). Is there a way of editing any notes that are related to the author in a given Book record ?

## **Update**

Based on the comments below, I've added the following foreign key to Note:
`Class Note(models.Model):
        note = models.TextField()
        author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
        book = models.ForeignKey(Book)`

and then
`Class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        model = Book
        inlines = [NoteInline]`

This allows me to access to see a notes field from within BookAdmin.

However when I enter a note from AuthorAdmin, rather than showing me this note in BookAdmin, a new blank note field is displayed.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I think if there is a relationship between Books and Notes. It should be represented in the domain model. If notes always have books, then they should have a relation to books and not authors.

The docs suggest using [Generic Relations as an inline](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#using-generic-relations-as-an-inline), but this would be a ridiculously restricted and round about approach.

Comment: Books won't always have notes, in fact I'm guessing there'll only be a note maybe 10% of all Books at best. That's why I wanted to move them to a separate table, rather than having lots of empty TextFields... Notes are really related to Books, but it does make sense to have them related to Author (eg a book review). Is there another way to have them related to Books and still have my inlines as discussed above ?

Comment: @mcrsam Do notes always have a related book? Or is Author the only guaranteed relation? To keep it simple I would just add a FK from Book to your Note model. Then your BookAdmin would just utilize a NoteInline. The relation could even be optional - if needed.

Comment: Ideally, notes should always have a related book (eg a note is a book review. Since I can't have nested inlines, relating the note to author also works). I tried adding the FK from Book to Note, but then the BookAdmin NoteInline shows a new note field rather than the existing note entry (max_num is set to 1)